# Kubernetes terminate job with multiple containers

Tags: kubernetes

I have job that is executing the test.
The job starts the pod with:

- test container
- sql server container

When the test container complete with failed/success exit code 1/0 then I want to terminate sql server container with exit code 0.

Is this feasible?

Comment: You'd almost always run a database in its own Pod, probably managed via a StatefulSet.  If you did that, the test Job would have only a single container and could exit normally.  You'd still need some higher-level tooling to tear down the database, but a shell script could be enough for simple cases.